# Best optimisation strategy for multiple timers in a C# application

Tags: c#, .net

In a C# app, there is a need to have 3 different polling intervals say 1 second, 6 seconds and 60 seconds. There are 2 ways I am thinking of.

1. Straightforward method of having 3 different timers with 3 different intervals.
2. Having one timer with 1 second interval and internally  having a counter variable for identifying 6 seconds (6 ticks) and 60 seconds (60 ticks) and so on.

Which is the best strategy considering memory and cpu utilisation. This app is targeted for a low end environment, so need to ensure optimisation.

Secondly, is there any .net timer api that fires different elapsed event at different intervals? Or any other strategy do you think fit this need.

Comment: Are you sure this is actually an optimization and it results in actual benefits? Latter most likely takes less memory, but the amount may be insignificant.

Comment: Timers are limited but that number is somewhere [in the thousands](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090827-00/?p=16963). Three timers is the same as none, don't solve a problem you don't have.

Comment: Realistically if difference between 1 and 3 timers is significant enough for your case you should stop using .Net and switch to C. And adjust intervals so you can fit all options into single byte checking when bit changes on increment (i.e. 1-8-64 you can check if 0th, 3rd and 6th bit changed and run corresponding callback)... More seriously - how you managed to measure your CPU/memory usage to notice significant difference between using one and three timers?

Comment: I wouldn't even bother with this. With single timer strategy you'll gain almost nothing as CPU consumption will remain the same (you'll offload it to application side from OS side) and memory gain will be literally insignificant. From the other hand you'll complicate your code and can lose the timers accuracy - all timers have some bias and in case of single timer strategy, you'll be under the risk that the bias will be accumulated unless you implement some algorithm which would compensate that but this will be another degree of complexity.

Comment: How important is the accuracy of the polling?
Do the actions at 1s, 6s, 60s intervals operate on the same data?
Are there 3 timers per <some event until completion> or only ever 3 globally forever?